# Como saber o valor que o "MATCH_PARENT" irá ter quando a view for desenhada?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou usando este código:

```
LayoutParams par = new LayoutParams(40, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

O segundo paramêntro, o `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` que representa a altura fica do tamanho de um layout horizontal que eu criei. No primeiro parâmetro eu coloquei 40 para ficar exatamente um quadrado (estou usando isso em um botão).

Eu precisava saber quantos pixels o `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` está usando e aplicar o mesmo no primeiro parâmetro, no lugar deste 40 para que meu botão ficasse quadrado independente da resolução do dispositivo que minha app for executada.

Comment: Onde quer a usar esse código? No `onCreate()` da Activity?

Comment: sim. eu chamo o método que uso este código no onCreate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As dimensões que são atribuídas à *view*, quando declaradas com `match_parent` ou `wrap_content`, só são calculadas na altura em que elas são apresentadas(*measurement fase*), isto só é feito depois do método `onCreate()` ser executado.

Uma das formas de contornar esta situação é declarar um *listenner* que é chamado após esse calculo.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    ....
    final View aSuaView = findViewById(R.id.aSuaView);
    aSuaView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 

        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                //Remove o listenner para não ser novamente chamado.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    aSuaView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    //noinspection deprecation
                    aSuaView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

                //Coloca a largura igual à altura
                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
                    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) aSuaView.getLayoutParams();
                 layoutParams.width = layoutParams.height;
                 aSuaView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
}
```