# Como obter o Width do ImageButton

Tags: java, android

Como posso obter o **width** de um ImageButton definido no **XML** como 0 sendo que este é definido pelo peso?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fluido"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:tint="@color/icon"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fluido" />

        <......../>

</LinearLayout>
```

Como faço para obter este valor que foi automaticamente definido pelo **weight**?

Como está setado no **XML** como **0**, se eu fizer: `imageButton.getWidth();` ou `imageButton.getLayoutParams().width();` ambos retornam 0 como está no **XML**.

Comment: Relacionado [Como saber o valor que o “MATCH_PARENT” irá ter quando a view for desenhada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98924/2541)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui aqui:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        // Dimensões corretas:
        int width  = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = view.getMeasuredHeight(); 
    } 
});
```