# Como verificar se um botão é visível durante a criação da activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Minha tela tem um botão e um FAB que fazem a mesma coisa e um scrollview, caso o scroll aconteça, eu verifico se o botão é visível ou não, se ele for visível, eu escondo o botão. Beleza, para o scroll, ele funciona muito bem. Meu problema é durante a criação da view e caso o conteúdo da tela seja pequeno e a tela muito grande, pois não há scroll e nesse caso, ele não esconde o FAB. Estou tentando verificar se o botão é visível logo após a criação da tela, mas não obtive sucesso.

Meu método para verificar a visibilidade do botão:

```
if (isViewVisible(binding.btnCall)) {
    binding.fabUpList.hide();
} else {
    binding.fabUpList.show();
}
private boolean isViewVisible(View view) {
    Rect mReact = new Rect();
    binding.nsvFreights.getHitRect(mReact);
    return view.getLocalVisibleRect(mReact);
}
```

Como verifico, logo após a criação da tela, se um componente está visível ou não?

Já tentei realizar essa verificação no onStart, onPostCreate e no onResume e nenhuma opção funcionou. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Talvez usando um ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener, veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99271/2541)

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado!